# For loop not terminating in c

Tags: c, for-loop

I am writing some code and I am getting a strange error: my for loop does not seem to exit when the condition statement becomes false. The code is as follows:

```
static void wstrcpy_from_Py_UNICODE(Py_UNICODE *inBuf, Py_ssize_t strLength, wchar_t **outBuf)
{
    if (strLength == 0) *outBuf = NULL;
    else
    {
        Py_ssize_t i;
        wprintf(L"String Length: %d\n", strLength);
        *outBuf = (wchar_t *)malloc (sizeof (wchar_t) * (strLength +1));
        for (i=0; i < strLength; i++)
        {
            wprintf("i:%d, strLength:%d\n", i, strLength);
            (*outBuf)[i] = (wchar_t)(inBuf[i]);
            wprintf(L"i < strLength: %d\n\n", i < strLength);
        }
    /* Make sure new string is zero terminated */
    (*outBuf)[i] = L'\0';
    }
}
```

When running this code with an example input, (The Py_UNICODE * buffer points to the internal unicode python object made with u"example") I get the following output:

```
String Length: 7
i:0, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:1, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:2, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:3, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:4, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:5, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:6, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:7, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

i:8, strLength: 7
i < strLength: 1

...
```

The loop doesn't exit until the python interpreter the code is running from (I am wrapping a c module for python) crashes.

The printf's were put in for debugging.

I am compiling this on Mac OSX 10.6, here are the commands I am using to compile:

```
gcc -c source.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/lib/python2.6
ld -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o out.so source.o -F./ -framework some_framework -macosx_version_min 10.6 -rpath ./
```

As you can see I am linking in the framework that I am making the python wrapper for. This is not a problem as I can call the functions just fine that use the linked framework, just when I call the function that uses the helper function shown above do I get the problem.

Am I being stupid here and doing something very basic wrong or is something wrong with the compiler? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Really weird bug! I think I'd take a peek at the assembly code to see what it did to the loop. I think the compiler screwed up something. Maybe the type definition of Py_ssize_t is confusing somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this mostly have to do with number precission. If `Py_ssize_t` is a 64 bit type, it *may* be of the form: `0xffffffff00000008` (maybe because a previous calculation value that involves incorrect precision numbers, or mixing signed with unsigned calculations). When considered as an `int` (32 bits), its result is 8, but when considered as a 64 bit value, it yields a very small negative number (signed), or a very big positive number (unsigned). Try to change the `wprintf` expressions to write a long decimal (`%ld`) and see what get's printed, or debug your code with gdb to see the number in its real size.

Comment: When I changed wprintf to use %ld, the number I got was 4294967303 which corresponds to 0x100000007. Good catch!

Answer (score 5):

Can you try using an int `i` and an int `strLength`?

I don't know `Py_ssize_t` type, but the implicit cast with the `%d` in `printf` might hide the issue

Comment: That worked! (well I cast the strLength to a new int and declared i as an int)

Comment: @user980127: be careful with that 'fix' - it's an indication that whoever is calling `wstrcpy_from_Py_UNICODE()` is passing `strLength` incorrectly (or maybe that you're supposed to be copying a huge string). The root cause of your problem is probably 'upstream' - you should pay attention to that instead of masking the problem inside `wstrcpy_from_Py_UNICODE()`.

Answer (score 3):

What's a `Py_ssize_t`?

```
printf("sizeof (int) is %d\n", (int)sizeof (int));
printf("sizeof (Py_ssize_t) is %d\n", (int)sizeof (Py_ssize_t));
```

Other than calling `wprintf` with a `char*` (once), you're using the `"%d"` specifier for values of type `Py_ssize_t`